# Soma de valores em duas colunas diferentes baseada em outras colunas em R

Tags: r, dataframe

Olá,

Estou tentando fazer a soma de gols feitos e gols sofridos de um conjunto de dados, alguém consegue me ajudar?

Basicamente tenho os dados da seguinte forma:

```
Mandante    Gols Feitos    Gols Sofridos    Visitante
Cruzeiro         0              1            Grêmio
Vitória          2              2            Flamengo
   .             .              .               .
   .             .              .               .
Fluminense       1              0            Cruzeiro
```

Quero então fazer uma tabela, como por exemplo:

```
Time       Gols Feitos    Gols Sofridos
Cruzeiro        0              2
Vitória         2              2
Fluminense      1              0
```

A pergunta se resume a, como somar o número de gols feitos quando mandante e o número de gols "sofridos" quando é visitante. Isso é relativamente simples fazer para um time, mas quero algo que sirva para todos os times. Alguma sugestão?

Amostra dos dados:

```
structure(list(Mandante = c("Cruzeiro", "Vitória", "Santos",
"América-MG", "Internacional", "Corinthians", "Vasco", "Atlético- 
PR","São Paulo", "Botafogo", "Bahia", "Flamengo", "Fluminense", "Paraná", 
"Ceará", "Chapecoense", "Palmeiras", "Atlético-MG", "Grêmio", 
"Sport"), `Gols feitos` = c(0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1), `Gols sofridos` = c(1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), Visitante = c("Grêmio", 
"Flamengo", "Ceará", "Sport", "Bahia", "Fluminense", "Atlético-MG", 
"Chapecoense", "Paraná", "Palmeiras", "Santos", "América-MG", 
"Cruzeiro", "Corinthians", "São Paulo", "Vasco", "Internacional", 
"Vitória", "Atlético-PR", "Botafogo")), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Aqui vai a minha sugestão

Havia um problema com o nome do Atlético-PR (tinha um \n no meio).

```
> test <- structure(list(Mandante = c("Cruzeiro", "Vitória", "Santos",
+ "América-MG", "Internacional", "Corinthians", "Vasco", "Atlético-PR","São Paulo", "Botafogo", "Bahia", "Flamengo", "Fluminense", "Paraná", 
+ "Ceará", "Chapecoense", "Palmeiras", "Atlético-MG", "Grêmio", 
+ "Sport"), `Gols feitos` = c(0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 
+ 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1), `Gols sofridos` = c(1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
+ 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), Visitante = c("Grêmio", 
+ "Flamengo", "Ceará", "Sport", "Bahia", "Fluminense", "Atlético-MG", 
+ "Chapecoense", "Paraná", "Palmeiras", "Santos", "América-MG", 
+ "Cruzeiro", "Corinthians", "São Paulo", "Vasco", "Internacional", 
+ "Vitória", "Atlético-PR", "Botafogo")), row.names = c(NA, -20L
+ ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

Fiz uma dataframe

```
> test <- data.frame(test)
> head(test)
       Mandante Gols.feitos Gols.sofridos  Visitante
1      Cruzeiro           0             1     Grêmio
2       Vitória           2             2   Flamengo
3        Santos           2             0      Ceará
4    América-MG           3             0      Sport
5 Internacional           2             0      Bahia
6   Corinthians           2             1 Fluminense
```

Fiz 2 data frame com os visitantes e mandantes, ambos com a mesma ordem de nomes:

```
> a <- test[,-4]
> a <- a[with(a, order(Mandante)), ]
> 
> b <- test[,-1]
> b <- b[with(b, order(Visitante)), ]
```

Confirmar que os nomes estão na mesma ordem:

```
> all.equal(b$Visitante, a$Mandante)
[1] TRUE
```

E no final é somar os golos marcados e sofridos:

```
> head(a)
      Mandante Gols.feitos Gols.sofridos
4   América-MG           3             0
18 Atlético-MG           2             1
8  Atlético-PR           5             1
11       Bahia           1             0
10    Botafogo           1             1
15       Ceará           0             0
> head(b)
   Gols.feitos Gols.sofridos   Visitante
12           2             0  América-MG
7            2             1 Atlético-MG
19           0             0 Atlético-PR
5            2             0       Bahia
20           1             1    Botafogo
3            2             0       Ceará
> a[,2] <- a[,2]+b[,2]
> head(a)
      Mandante Gols.feitos Gols.sofridos
4   América-MG           3             0
18 Atlético-MG           3             1
8  Atlético-PR           5             1
11       Bahia           1             0
10    Botafogo           2             1
15       Ceará           0             0
> a[,3]<- a[,3]+b[,1]
> head(a)
      Mandante Gols.feitos Gols.sofridos
4   América-MG           3             2
18 Atlético-MG           3             3
8  Atlético-PR           5             1
11       Bahia           1             2
10    Botafogo           2             2
15       Ceará           0             2
```

E agora fiz a tabela final:

```
> final <- a
> colnames(final) <- c("Time", "Gols Feitos", "Gols Sofridos")
> head(final)
          Time Gols Feitos Gols Sofridos
4   América-MG           3             2
18 Atlético-MG           3             3
8  Atlético-PR           5             1
11       Bahia           1             2
10    Botafogo           2             2
15       Ceará           0             2
```

Espero que ajude.